# Why can this script access another script without it being instantiated?

Tags: c#, class, oop, unity-game-engine, reference

I followed a tutorial in which someone wrote "public Inventory Container;" with which he could access data from the Inventory-Script. Why is this possible? I thought you can only access a non-instantiated script if it's static. Thanks for the help

**First Script:**

```
        [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Inventory",  menuName = "Inventory System/Inventory")]
public class InventoryObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public Inventory Container;

    public void AddItem(Item _item, int _amount)
    {
        if (_item.buffs.Length > 0)
        {
            Container.Items.Add(new InventorySlot(_item.Id, _item, _amount));
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Container.Items.Count; i++) //Checks if already has the item.
        {
            if(Container.Items[i].item.Id == _item.Id)
            {
                Container.Items[i].AddAmount(_amount); /*If the item already exits, it just increases the number of it. 
                AddAmount works, because the Container consists of InventorySlot.*/
                return;
            }
        }
            Container.Items.Add(new InventorySlot(_item.Id, _item, _amount)); /*If Item doesn't exist, it adds it using the InventorySlot Constructor.*/ 
    }
}
```

**Script being accessed:**

```
   [System.Serializable]
    public class Inventory
    {
        public List<InventorySlot> Items = new List<InventorySlot>();
    }
```

Comment: `Inventory` is just a regular C# class.  It's not a MonoBehaviour so it doesn't have to be a component of a game object.

Answer (score 1):

`Inventory` is `Serializable`, which means when you change the `Container` in the inspector when editing your game, Unity will serialize that instance.

Then, when the game starts Unity will deserialize it and assign it back to `Container` for whichever instance of `InventoryObject` you were editing.

See [The Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) for further details:

> #### Inspector window
>
> When you view or change the value of a GameObject’s component field in the Inspector window, Unity serializes this data and then displays it in the Inspector
> window.